# Sum of columns based on Minute

Tags: shell, unix, awk

Below is my input file:

- 1st column is combination of Hour of day and Minute
- 2nd column is count

the data is minute wise.

I need to convert the data into minute wise by summing on each block of minutes, i.e [1-5, 6-10 and so on]. I need this data to plot in jfree chart. Please suggest how get the output

Input:

```
11.01:5
11.02:4
11.03:3
11.04:8
11.05:2
12.11:3
12.12:4
12.13:1
12.15:0
13.03:04
22.56:01
22.57:03
22.58:2
23.00:0
```

Output:

```
11.05:22
12.15:8
13.05:4
23.00:6
```

Comment: yes. Because there is no data for 13.01,13.02. i want the output in 5th minute only

Comment: can you elaborate more, its not very clear.

Comment: @user1580770 Do you not want to round to the nearest 5 ? Because `22.56` and `22.57` would both round down to `22.55`

Comment: @Jidder apparently all gets rounded to the upper 5. 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 --> 5, whereas 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 -> 0. I did a little diagram in my answer :D

Comment: @fedorqui i know, was just wondering if OP realised thats what they were doing, i added both to my answer just in case :) I used modulus instead though :D(well your int division is pretty much mod anyway)

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F '[.:,]' -v OFS=: '{
   p=5*int(($2+4)/5);
   $1=1*$1;
   if(p==60){
      p="0";
      $1++
   }
   k=sprintf("%02d.%02d", $1, p)
}
!s[k]{
   b[++n]=k
}
{
   s[k]+=$3
}
END{
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      print b[i],s[b[i]]
}' file
11.05:22
12.15:8
13.05:4
23.00:6
```

Comment: 04:15,39
04:20,225
04:25,208
04:30,263
04:35,311
04:40,270
04:45,287
04:50,264
04:55,261
5:00,191
05:00,42
05:05,221
05:10,227
05:15,225
05:20,219
05:25,208
05:30,207
05:35,214
05:40,207
05:45,250
05:50,241
05:55,243
6:00,207
06:00,46
06:05,233
06:10,243
06:15,260
06:20,241
06:25,244
06:30,242
06:35,222
06:40,241
06:45,287
06:50,226
06:55,222
7:00,168
07:00,47
07:05,438
07:10,260
07:15,256
07:20,290
07:25,256
07:30,249
07:35,249
07:40,256
07:45,299
07:50,244
07:55,284
8:00,229
08:00,56
08:05,283
08:10,263
08:15,302
08:20,154

Comment: Difficult to read it from comment, can you edit your question with this data

Comment: @user1580770: You original input was in `hh.mm:count` format but what you have here is in `hh:mm,count` format, they are both different. I am making a change to take care of both formats but you should clarify this in question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a draft. Once you show some of your attempts I will provide a more generic approach:

```
awk -F"[.:]" -v OFS=":" '{r=sprintf("%d", ($2-1)/5); r=(r+1)*5; a[$1"."r]+=$3} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
```

For your given input it returns:

```
22.60:6
13.5:4
12.15:8
23.5:0
11.5:22
```

The key point is to map every 1,2,3,4 and 5 to the 5. This I do by saying:

```
d -> d-1 -> (d-1)/5 (int division) -> (d-1)/5 * 5
```

---

To make sure no minutes `60` are appearing, you can add some condition: `if (r==60) {r=0; $1++}`:

```
$ awk -F"[.:]" -v OFS=":" '{r=sprintf("%d", ($2-1)/5); r=(r+1)*5; if (r==60) {r=0; $1++}; a[$1"."r]+=$3} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
23.0:6
13.5:4
12.15:8
23.5:0
11.5:22
```

You can do also some fancy things like printing a leading `0` for minutes <10 and just print those values that do sum >0:

```
$ awk -F"[.:]" -v OFS=":" '{r=sprintf("%d", ($2-1)/5); r=(r+1)*5; if (r==60) {r=0; $1++}; r=sprintf("%02d", r); a[$1"."r]+=$3} END {for (i in a) if (a[i]) print i, a[i]}' file
11.05:22
12.15:8
13.05:4
23.00:6
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved a million different ways: sed, awk, python, etc.

Here is how you can do it with common bash commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract the unique set of hours from the input (i.e. 11, 12, 13, 22, 23)
#
hours=$(cut -f 1 -d . test.txt | sort -u)
for hour in $hours; do

    # initialize sum for this hour
    #
    count=0

    # extract the number following the ':'
    #
    for x in $(grep "^$hour" test.txt | cut -f 2 -d :); do
        # sum up the numbers following the ':'
        #
        count=$(($count + $x))
    done

    # Extract the last timestamp for the given hour
    #
    t=$(grep "^$hour" test.txt | tail -1  | cut -f 1 -d :)

    # Print the desired output of timestamp:sum
    #
    echo $t:$count
done
```

Here is the output:

```
11.05:22
12.15:8
13.03:4
22.58:6
23.00:0
```

Your input is stored in the file test.txt:

```
11.01:5
11.02:4
11.03:3
11.04:8
11.05:2
12.11:3
12.12:4
12.13:1
12.15:0
13.03:04
22.56:01
22.57:03
22.58:2
23.00:0
```

Let me point our some of the commands you see in the script

1. `cut` used to extract columns from input.  `cut -f 1 -d .` will extract the hour from your input.  `-f 1` says print column 1 and `-d .` says use '.' as the deliminator.
2. `tail -f 1` prints the last line from tail's input.
3. `sort -u` removes duplicates lines from the input.

Answer (score 0):

One more awk

If you want to round to nearest 5

```
awk -F"[.:]" '{$2=(t=($2%5))>2?$2-t+5:$2-t;if($2==60){$1++;$2=0};a[$1]+=$3;b[$1]=$2}
              END{for(i in b)print i"."b[i]":"a[i]}' file
```

If you want to just round up everything that isn't a multiple of 5.

```
awk -F"[.:]" '{$2=$2%5!=0?$2-($2%5)+5:$2;if($2==60){$1++;$2=0};a[$1]+=$3;b[$1]=$2}
              END{for(i in b)print i"."b[i]":"a[i]}' file
```

#### Output for round to nearest multiple of 5

```
11.5:22
12.15:8
22.55:4
13.5:4
23.0:2
```

#### Round up to next multiple of 5

```
11.05:22
12.15:8
13.5:4
23.00:6
```

As you can see in the output this will round to the nearest 5 which is why 22.55 is present

#### How the rounding works

Modulus gives the remainder when a number is divided by another

`24/5 = 4 remainder 4`

so

`24%5 = 4`

So to round the number down to the next multiple of X we simply have to subtract the remainder so

`N-(N%X)` 
`24-(24%5)`

will always be a multiple of `X` (rounded down).

To round up we simply say if result of the modulus is more than half of `X` (in this case 5), then add X to the result to round to the next multiple of X

`(N-(N%X))+X`
`(24-(24%5))+5`

Not sure if this is the best way to round but it works :)